# Python multiprocessing - read a input file, start a process for each file and start "3" processes at one point of time

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a filelist that contains a list of input files for a process called "Analysis".
I have written a python code that reads this filelist and starts this process "Analysis" for each line in the file.
Also checks if the count of processes is less than or equal to 3. If the count is less than 3, read the next line and start the next process. If count is already 3, then wait for any one of the process to end, untill the next one starts.
Basically, the idea is to run 3 processes at a time

This is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import psutil
import getpass
from time import time, sleep

def app_call():
        with open('file_list', 'r') as mf:
               for line in mf:
                        print(line)
                        cmd = "analysis "  + line.strip() 
                        print(cmd)
                        os.system(cmd)

def start_3_process():
        while True:
                sleep(60 - time() % 60)
                count = sum(1 for proc in psutil.process_iter() if proc.name() == 'analysis' and proc.username() == getpass.getuser())
                print(count)
                if( count < 3 ):
                        print("no of process is less than 3")
                        app_call()
                else:
                        print("no of process is " + str(count))

start_3_process()
```

The problem here is when the process count falls below 3, this script again starts reading the file_list till line5 and then again starts reading from line 1 and again the process call starts from line 1 in the file to line 5.
The filelist has 5 lines like

```
input1
input2
input3
input4
input5
```

how can i make my code robust, like when the 5 lines are read from my file, the read should not be repeated.
this code runs on python 2.x

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is put all the input in a Queue,ask threading to get them.this won't repeat to read.

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import time
import Queue
import threading


class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name, q):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.q = q

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            try:
                things_to_be_done(self.name, self.q)
            except Queue.Empty:
                break


def things_to_be_done(name, q):
    q_obj = q.get(timeout=1)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(name)


def main(link_list, time):
    thread_list = [str(n) for n in range(time)]
    length = len(link_list)
    queue = Queue.Queue(length)

    threads = []
    for q_obj in link_list:
        queue.put(q_obj)

    for name in thread_list:
        thread = myThread(name, queue)
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    times = 3
    link_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    main(link_list, times)
```